# Kotlin smart cast failing on Iterable<*>

Tags: kotlin

Can somebody explain please, why this construction fails to compile, even though according to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#type-erasure-and-generic-type-checks) it should do smart cast?

```
                if (user.profile[attrName] is Iterable<*>) {
                    user.profile[attrName]
                        .map { value -> value.toString() }
                        .joinToString(",")
                        .contains(attrVal)
```

with
 `Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch  ... (bunch of Kotlin collection classes) ... public inline fun <T, R> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.map(transform: (TypeVariable(T)) -> TypeVariable(R)): List<TypeVariable(R)> defined in kotlin.collections`

but when I explicitly do `val coll = user.profile[attrName] as Iterable<*>` then it compiles just fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`profile[attrName]` is not a variable or a `val` property. It is an expression that uses a getter to get some value from another class. The compiler cannot guarantee that that class will return the exact same value in between your `is` check and the next time you call it. If you assign it to a local variable, it is no longer an expression, so it can be smart-casted:

```
val attrName = user.profile[attrName]
if (attrName is Iterable<*>) {
    attrName 
        .map { value -> value.toString() }
        .joinToString(",")
        .contains(attrVal)
```